# Why is value 'not an object' in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I am writing a script that is supposed to go through all of the forms on the page and determine whether or not the value should be changed.  In error console, I get the following error:

```
Timestamp: 9/8/2013 11:16:14 PM
Error: TypeError: Value not an object.
Source File: http://localhost/admin/transform.js
Line: 22
```

This is my code:

```
function transform() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('transform');

    for(var i = 0; i <= forms.length; i++){
        var inputs = forms[i].getElementsByTagName("input");

        for(var ri = 0; ri <= inputs.length; ri++){
            if(inputs[ri].type == "text"){
                inputs[ri].value = "This is a test.";  
            }
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("onLoad", 'transform', false);
```

Line 22 is the event listener.  Why is "value" not working?

Comment: Should `'transform'` be `transform`?

Comment: I tried that.  With that, nothing happens.  No errors in console, either.

Comment: Oops, I also missed the `"on"` part. That whole statement should be `window.addEventListener("load",transform,false);`.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I assumed "value" meant the inpus[ri].value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. The first parameter to `window.addEventListener` is case sensitive. It should be `'load'`, not `'onLoad'`. See this list: http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php
2. The second parameter to `window.addEventListener` expects a function, not a string. It should be `transform`, not `'transform'`.